# During maven deployment through gitlab ci/cd, some dependency transform times vary wildly

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-dependency

I used the -X flag on mvn deploy to see why our maven deployment lengths could very between 5 and 30 minutes. What I have found is that dependency collection stats for our various submodules varies wildly between a few seconds and, say, 15 minutes. For example, here is one such example from a recent deployment:

```
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1270166, ConflictMarker.markTime=518139, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=3255, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=763154, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=199381, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=291, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=10694587, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=815, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=900188135454, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=13470017}
```

This demonstrates that "collectTime" is about 15 minutes. That same module in a different deployment took 697508653 nanoseconds i.e. 0.0116 minutes. But, in that other deployment, a different module took a long time instead.

What could cause this step to take such a huge amount of time, seemingly at random? How can I learn more?

Comment: Do you run your own Neuxs/Artifactory, or do you directly contact remote repositories?

Comment: @JFabianMeier Yes, my company uses its own nexus.